# Can I encrypt the LUKS encrypted disk a second time with TrueCrypt

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

When installing linux, I encrypted it with the LUKS, can I encrypt it a second time with another program? Will the system be double encrypted?

Comment: Please note, you may also want to ask the question "Does it add security value to encrypt twice" on [security.se], because your question implies you may be surprised by the answer to that question...

Comment: @SEJPM Is there such a question now? You're implying you know what the answer is, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can double-encrypt the drive in the way you envisage, but it is not of much value at significant extra cost.

Linux uses a concept of block devices, and you you can have layered levels of encryption, each acting on the block above.    Luks takes a block device, and  provides another block device with the unencrypted data.

I've not (and see no reason to) use FDE on an encrypted drive, however multiple blocks are common - for example  Software RAID (level 1) providing a DRBD block (level 2) for LVM (level 3) providing Encryption (level 4) is an entirely normal way of setting things up - and yes, depending on your exact goal, you can layer things in a different way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I understand, so double-encryption will not significantly improve the quality of security?
I do not want to rely on one program only.
So the same value will be encrypted twice, once by AES (LUKS) and the second time by Kuznyechik (VeraCrypt)?

Comment: Assuming Veracrypt used Kuzneychik encryption - whatever that is - yes. I think consensus is that the encryption behind AES is solid - attacks are more likely against the implementation.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help


Kuznyechik is a Russian replacement AES algorithm.
Developed in 2015 at the request of the Russian government :)